# Как добавить DevExpress в проект

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Мне нужно использовать

```
using DevExpress.Data.Filtering;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Grid;
```

как добавить это в проект? Через Nugget? Как понять что именно из списка в Nugget мне надо, или гуглить dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще вам нужно установить DevExpress, при установки dll пропишутся в GAC, а потом вы уже добавите нужные вам непосредсвенно в проекте. [триальная версия](https://go.devexpress.com/devexpressdownload_universaltrial.aspx).

Comment: Добавить как обычную dll в reference в проекте?

Comment: @Winteriscoming да

Comment: trial версия она урезанная или через какой то время перестанет работать?

Comment: Полная, ограничение по  времени.